# Unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am connecting to an external wsdl and attempting to send some messages back and forth.
No complexity is required just attempting to send some data across and get a confirmation message back. 
My problem right now is that i've got a marshalling error:

```
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

and this seems to come from the line:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:311)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
>       at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
>       at DVSClient.main(DVSClient.java:59)
>   Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:234)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.LeafBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(LeafBeanInfoImpl.java:127)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleReferenceNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleReferenceNodeProperty.java:100)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:345)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:336)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:336)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:578)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:326)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:479)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
>   Blockquote

My main code is as follows:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {


    URL UrlString = new URL("https://example.com.au:19443/Bus/exampleservice.svc?wsdl");
    String url02 = "https://example.com.au:19443/Bus/exampleservice.svc?wsdl";

    //Qname contains target namespace and name (port)
    QName qname = new QName("http://example/Contract/Service/Manager", "VerificationServiceBus", "Https");
    QName port = new QName("http://example/Contract/Service/Manager","DefaultSOAP11Binding_IVerification","Https");
    QName portName = new QName("Https");
    String serviceName = "VerificationServiceBus";
    CertificateRequest certificate = (new TestData()).test();
    URL newEndpoint = new URL("https://example.com.au:19443:19443/Bus/VerificationServiceBus.svc?");
    Service service = Service.create(UrlString, qname);

    try {

        IVerification myProxy = service.getPort(port,IVerification.class);

        VerificationResponse response = myProxy.verifyDocument(birthCertificate);
        System.out.println(response.getVerificationResultCode());

    }
    catch (IVerificationVerifyDocumentUnauthorizedAccessExceptionFaultFaultMessage ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }
}
```

}

I've tried manually going into some of the classes and adding @XMLRootElement into the classes with name attributes but still the same sort error.

From what I understand Marshalling and unmarshalling has to do with transforming the memory representation of an object to a format more suitable for transforming. Though since all my classes are generated shouldnt this be handled for me?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The 'top' or 'root' Java object from what you need to serialize / deserialize must have the bespoken XmlRootElement annotation. In your code it looks like this could be the VerificationResponse response? And yes, you are right, if IVerification and VerificationResponse are generated, they shall get the XmlRootElement by the generation process.

Comment: So i tried adding the annotation everywhere to no luck.
Iike...

    ' @XmlRootElement(name="VerificationResponse")
public class VerificationResponse {'